# Activated ability that share a name

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If i have two [Vector Asp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194074)'s on the battlefield and I attack with both.
If I use the ability, "{B}:Vector Asp gains infect until end of turn", do I have to pay twice (once for each attacking Vector Asp) or only once?

Comment: And... https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/does-goblin-arsonists-ability-deal-2-damage-when-there-are-two-in-play/. In fact we appear to have at least 6 questions which all have the same answer, although each is asking about a different card/ability.

Comment: I like the canonical answer because the previously asked questions are with regard to triggered abilities, activated abilities, etc. etc. and having a general case to link duplicates to is good. I knew this question was a duplicate when I saw it but I didn't know which previous question to link it to.

Answer (score 2):

When a card refers to it's own name in text, it isn't actually referring to cards with that name; it's referring to itself.

So Vector Asp's activated ability actually means: "{B}: **This Card** gains infect until end of turn". You can attack with both Vector Asps, and activate each ability separately, to give one, both or neither of them infect.

Some cards will refer to other cards with a certain name, but this is usually formatted as "... a card named ~" (eg. [Accumulated Knowledge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=21285)).

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the ability of each card separately.

When a card refers to itself by name, it refers to that specific object only.

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless
>   of any name changes caused by game effects.